# process_item pipeline not called

Tags: python, sqlite, scrapy, pipeline

I'm new to python and scrapy

After scraping process I tried to save database to mysqlite,
Follow by this src : https://github.com/sunshineatnoon/Scrapy-Amazon-Sqlite( from [url](https://sunshineafternoonweb.wordpress.com/2017/01/30/how-to-use-scrapy-to-scrape-amazon-com-and-save-to-sqlite/))

My problem is database was created successfully but items can't be inserted to database because **process_item** not called

*EDIT*

I paste the source code from github link above 
setting.py

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'amazon.pipelines.AmazonPipeline': 300
    }
```

pipelines.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define your item pipelines here
#
# Don't forget to add your pipeline to the ITEM_PIPELINES setting
# See: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
import sqlite3
import os
con = None


class AmazonPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.setupDBCon()
        self.createTables()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        print('---------------process item----')
        self.storeInDb(item)
        return item

    def setupDBCon(self):
        self.con = sqlite3.connect(os.getcwd() + '/test.db')
        self.cur = self.con.cursor()

    def createTables(self):
        self.dropAmazonTable()
        self.createAmazonTable()

    def dropAmazonTable(self):
        #drop amazon table if it exists
        self.cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Amazon")

    def closeDB(self):
        self.con.close()

    def __del__(self):
        self.closeDB()

    def createAmazonTable(self):
        self.cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Amazon(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, \
            name TEXT, \
            path TEXT, \
            source TEXT \
            )")

        self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO Amazon(name, path, source ) VALUES( 'Name1', 'Path1', 'Source1')")
        print ('------------------------')
        self.con.commit()      


    def storeInDb(self,item):
        # self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO Amazon(\
        #     name, \
        #     path, \
        #     source \
        #     ) \
        # VALUES( ?, ?, ?)", \
        # ( \
        #     item.get('Name',''),
        #     item.get('Path',''),
        #     item.get('Source','')
        # ))

        self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO Amazon(name, path, source ) VALUES( 'Name1', 'Path1', 'Source1')")

        print ('------------------------')
        print ('Data Stored in Database')
        print ('------------------------')
        self.con.commit()
```

spiders/amazonspider.py

```
import scrapy
import urllib
from amazon.items import AmazonItem
import os


class amazonSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    imgcount = 1
    name = "amazon"
    allowed_domains = ["amazon.com"]
    '''
    start_urls = ["http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=backpack",
                  "http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_2?rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Abackpack&page=2&keywords=backpack&ie=UTF8&qid=1442907452&spIA=B00YCRMZXW,B010HWLMMA"
                  ]
    '''
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request("http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_ex_n_3?rh=n%3A7141123011%2Cn%3A10445813011%2Cn%3A9479199011%2Cn%3A360832011&bbn=10445813011&ie=UTF8&qid=1442910853&ajr=0",self.parse)

        for i in range(2,3):
            yield scrapy.Request("http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=lp_360832011_pg_2?rh=n%3A7141123011%2Cn%3A10445813011%2Cn%3A9479199011%2Cn%3A360832011&page="+str(i)+"&bbn=10445813011&ie=UTF8&qid=1442910987",self.parse)



    def parse(self,response):
        #namelist = response.xpath('//a[@class="a-link-normal s-access-detail-page  a-text-normal"]/@title').extract()
        #htmllist = response.xpath('//a[@class="a-link-normal s-access-detail-page  a-text-normal"]/@href').extract()
        #imglist = response.xpath('//a[@class="a-link-normal a-text-normal"]/img/@src').extract()
        namelist = response.xpath('//a[@class="a-link-normal s-access-detail-page s-overflow-ellipsis a-text-normal"]/@title').extract()
        htmllist = response.xpath('//a[@class="a-link-normal s-access-detail-page s-overflow-ellipsis a-text-normal"]/@href').extract()
        imglist = response.xpath('//img[@class="s-access-image cfMarker"]/@src').extract()
        listlength = len(namelist)

        pwd = os.getcwd()+'/'

        if not os.path.isdir(pwd+'crawlImages/'):
            os.mkdir(pwd+'crawlImages/')

        for i in range(0,listlength):
            item = AmazonItem()
            item['Name'] = namelist[i]
            item['Source'] = htmllist[i]

            urllib.urlretrieve(imglist[i],pwd+"crawlImages/"+str(amazonSpider.imgcount)+".jpg")
            item['Path'] = pwd+"crawlImages/"+str(amazonSpider.imgcount)+".jpg"
            amazonSpider.imgcount = amazonSpider.imgcount + 1
            yield item
```

**Result**
after run `scrapy crawl amazone`
I have **test.db** created but item haven't inserted (I've checked my sqlite db.test), that mean `process_item` was not run

build result

```
2018-09-18 16:38:38 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.1 started (bot: amazon)
2018-09-18 16:38:38 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.1.0, libxml2 2.9.8, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.0, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 17.5.0, Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 26 2018, 08:42:37) - [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)], pyOpenSSL 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018), cryptography 2.2.2, Platform Darwin-17.7.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
2018-09-18 16:38:38 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'amazon', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'amazon.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['amazon.spiders']}
2018-09-18 16:38:38 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2018-09-18 16:38:38 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2018-09-18 16:38:38 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
------------------------
2018-09-18 16:38:38 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['amazon.pipelines.AmazonPipeline']
2018-09-18 16:38:38 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-09-18 16:38:38 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-09-18 16:38:38 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2018-09-18 16:38:38 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=lp_360832011_pg_2?rh=n%3A7141123011%2Cn%3A10445813011%2Cn%3A9479199011%2Cn%3A360832011&page=2&bbn=10445813011&ie=UTF8&qid=1442910987> from <GET http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=lp_360832011_pg_2?rh=n%3A7141123011%2Cn%3A10445813011%2Cn%3A9479199011%2Cn%3A360832011&page=2&bbn=10445813011&ie=UTF8&qid=1442910987>
2018-09-18 16:38:38 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_ex_n_3?rh=n%3A7141123011%2Cn%3A10445813011%2Cn%3A9479199011%2Cn%3A360832011&bbn=10445813011&ie=UTF8&qid=1442910853&ajr=0> from <GET http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_ex_n_3?rh=n%3A7141123011%2Cn%3A10445813011%2Cn%3A9479199011%2Cn%3A360832011&bbn=10445813011&ie=UTF8&qid=1442910853&ajr=0>
2018-09-18 16:38:39 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.amazon.com/backpacks/b?ie=UTF8&node=360832011> from <GET https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_ex_n_3?rh=n%3A7141123011%2Cn%3A10445813011%2Cn%3A9479199011%2Cn%3A360832011&bbn=10445813011&ie=UTF8&qid=1442910853&ajr=0>
2018-09-18 16:38:39 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.amazon.com/Backpacks-Luggage-Travel-Gear/s?ie=UTF8&page=2&rh=n%3A360832011> from <GET https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=lp_360832011_pg_2?rh=n%3A7141123011%2Cn%3A10445813011%2Cn%3A9479199011%2Cn%3A360832011&page=2&bbn=10445813011&ie=UTF8&qid=1442910987>
2018-09-18 16:38:40 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/Backpacks-Luggage-Travel-Gear/s?ie=UTF8&page=2&rh=n%3A360832011> (referer: None)
2018-09-18 16:38:40 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/backpacks/b?ie=UTF8&node=360832011> (referer: None)
2018-09-18 16:38:41 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2018-09-18 16:38:41 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1909,
 'downloader/request_count': 6,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 6,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 140740,
 'downloader/response_count': 6,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 4,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 18, 9, 38, 41, 53948),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 7,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'memusage/max': 52600832,
 'memusage/startup': 52600832,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 6,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 6,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 6,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 6,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 18, 9, 38, 38, 677280)}
2018-09-18 16:38:41 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

I've searching around but have no luck

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide some code or configuraiton so it's easier to understand whats going wrong?

Comment: Have you double checked your `settings.py` actually has that pipeline enabled? (eg: You have an uncommented `ITEM_PIPELINES = {...}` that includes the pipeline you want to be used)

Comment: @ThomasStrub, @ Jon Clements I've edited the with the built result and src code.  ITEM_PIPELINES have enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I crawl

```
https://www.amazon.com/backpacks/b?ie=UTF8&node=360832011
```

I don't get any result in namelist and htmllist. Urllist is filled. 
Checking the html-code:

```
... <a class="a-link-normal s-access-detail-page s-overflow-ellipsis s-color-twister-title-link a-text-normal" ...
```

I found an additional "s-color-twister-title-link" so your specific xpath is not correct. You can add the s-color-twister-title-link

```
In [9]: response.xpath('//a[@class="a-link-normal s-access-detail-page s-overflow-ellipsis s-
   ...: color-twister-title-link a-text-normal"]/@title').extract()
Out[9]: 
['Anime Anti-theft Backpack, Luminous School Bag, Waterproof Laptop Backpack with USB Charging Port, Unisex 15.6 Inch College Daypack, Starry',
 'Anime Luminous Backpack Noctilucent School Bags Daypack USB chargeing Port Laptop Bag Handbag for Boys Girls Men Women',
```

or you can use a more specific one like:

```
response.xpath('//a[contains(@class,"s-access-detail-page")]/@title').extract()
```

Comment: thanks Thomas, you are right, the issue from the spider so process item not called, I believed process_item called before